# Como executar o loop for de 2 em 2?

Tags: javascript, for

Minha solução:

```
function passandoPelosPares() {
for (var i=0; i <=6; i++)
  console.log ('aqui eu tenho o valor de' + i)
}
```

Resposta 'insuficiente':

> Imprimir `passandoPelosPares()` deve imprimir:
>
> ```
> aqui eu tenho o valor de 0
> aqui eu tenho o valor de 2
> aqui eu tenho o valor de 4
> aqui eu tenho o valor de 6
> ```

O que eu tô fazendo de errado?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente faltava um espaço na impressão, o corretor automático do site quer algo exato, não pode errar nem o espaço. Mas eu aproveitei e simplifiquei e dei mais performance para o código tirando o `if`, não faz sentido ter esse código se pode fazer sem ele.

```js
function passandoPelosPares() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i += 2) console.log('aqui eu tenho o valor de ' + i);
}
passandoPelosPares();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/StepTwo.js).

Coloquei a chamada da função só para executar aqui, lá nesse site ele deve chamar por conta própria e não precisa desta linha.

Comment: Obrigada, eu refiz a solução e funcionou!

Answer (score 3):

No seu código no loop `for` você está adicionando sempre mais `1` na variável `i` a cada iteração do loop `for` o que não vai te dar o resultado em `2` e `2` e sim em `1` em `1`, então altere de `i ++` para `i += 2`, adicione um espaço no final da `String` para não ficar junto o texto e o número e é só chamar a função `passandoPelosPares();`.

**Exemplo 1**

```js
function passandoPelosPares() {
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i += 2)
  console.log ('aqui eu tenho o valor de ' + i)
}

passandoPelosPares();
```

Caso você queira que uma sequência em `2, 4, 6` e não `0, 2, 4, 6` é só iniciar a variável `i` com `2` e não com `0`.

**Exemplo 2**

```js
function passandoPelosPares() {
for (var i = 2; i <= 6; i += 2)
  console.log ('aqui eu tenho o valor de ' + i)
}

passandoPelosPares();
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada pela contribuição.

Answer (score 1):

Executei o seu código e o resultado obtido foi:

```
aqui eu tenho o valor de0
aqui eu tenho o valor de2
aqui eu tenho o valor de4
aqui eu tenho o valor de6
```

O que me leva a crer que o problema é o espaço entre o "de" e o "par".

Neste caso, simplesmente substitua o "+" por "," no seu `console.log`.

Você também não precisa do `if` se o passo do seu `for` for de 2 em 2, trocando `i++` por `i+=2`.

Além disso, pode ser que falte executar a função, e você pode fazer isso envolvendo a função com `()` e colocando os parêntesis no final, desta maneira:

```js
(function passandoPelosPares() { 
    for (var i=0; i <=6; i+=2) 
        console.log ('aqui eu tenho o valor de', i) 
})()
```

Comment: Obrigada pelas contribuições.

Comment: Mas, nenhuma das soluções funcionou.