# Função com for()

Tags: javascript, for

Estou com um problema num exercício. Neste exercício, devo implementar uma função chamada `passandoPelosPares()` que mostra pelo console `aqui eu tenho o valor de x` para cada valor PAR que percorra i de 0 até e inclusive 6.

> Dica:
>
> Para saber se um número é par, usamos o operador % (módulo) que me retorna o resto da divisão de um número por outro. Por exemplo: 11 % 5 retorna o resto da divisão 11 por 5, que neste caso retorna 1.

Minha função criada:

```js
function passandoPelosPares(){
  
  for (var i = 0; i<=6; i++){
    
    if(i%2==0||i%4==2||i%6==4||i%8==6){
     console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de " + i); 

  }
 }  
}
```

Porém mesmo retornando os valores corretos até o 6, ainda está sendo apresentado o seguinte erro:

```
'[object Object]' == 'aqui eu tenho o valor de 0\naqui eu tenho o valor de 2\naqui eu tenho o valor de 4\naqui eu tenho o valor de 6\n'
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O resultado parece ser o esperado, apesar de seu if ter mais verificações que o necessário. Qual erro está sendo apresentado?

Comment: Concordo com o Daniel Mendes. Dá para provar que, se `x % 2*n == 2*m`, então `x % 2 == 0` é verdade. Logo, tudo após a primeira condicional é redundante: eles só podem dar verdadeiro se a primeira condição (`i % 2 == 0`) for verdade, e sempre darão falso quando a primeira condição também for falsa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento pessoal.

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Executando sua função, não está ocorrendo este erro que você está afirmando. Isso que você está interpretando como erro é na verdade apenas o reflexo do código no inspetor de código de seu browser ou app que esta utilizando.

Existe outra pegunta envolvendo a mesma função aqui. Para mais esclarecimento veja: [Como executar o loop for de 2 em 2?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423756/como-executar-o-loop-for-de-2-em-2/424138#424138)

```js
function passandoPelosPares(){
   for (var i = 0; i<=6; i++){
      if(i%2==0||i%4==2||i%6==4||i%8==6){
         console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de " + i); 
      } 
   }
}

passandoPelosPares();
```

Clique no "Executar" e veja o resultado normal, conforme esperado por você.

Comment: Valmor flores, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

só fazer o laço de repetilçao e o IF comparando se o divisor dele é igual a 0! o divisor igual a 0 sempre é um numero par.

function passandoPelosPares(){
for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) { 
  console.log("aqui eu tenho o valor de "+i)
}
}
}